# GET or POST with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Trying to modify the RateIT star rating system to store votes in SQL db. Upon user input the script runs and mySQL records the data. However I am unable to receive an updated average value from SQL.

How do Run a query and send it back to AJAX and display it. Should POST or GET be used?

Im extremely confused, struggling with this for days. I've looked at examples and previous questions here and with RateIT but nothing seems to fit .

Code: would like the results to display in id="response"

HTML and JS

```
    <div id="products">
       <div>
         <ul id="response">
         </ul>
       </div>    
    </div>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
         $('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
             var ri = $(this);
     var value = ri.rateit('value');
             var productID = ri.data('productid');
              ri.rateit('readonly', true);
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'rate.php',
                 data: { productID: productID, value: value }, 
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('#response').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
                 },
                 error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                     $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                 }
             });
         });
    </script>
```

PHP

```
     <?PHP
        $con=mysqli_connect ("host","user","pass#","dbname");
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[productID]','$_POST[value]',now())");
        mysqli_close($con);
        exit;
              ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

edited php code:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date)          VALUES        ('$_POST[storyidr]','$_POST[value]',now()) THEN SELECT AVG(rank) AS avrank from ratings WHERE storyidr=$storyidr;" );

$avgrate = $data['avrank'];
if(!$result)
 {
  $arr = array ('status'=>'fail');
  echo json_encode($arr);
}
else
{
     $arr = array ($avgrate);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: 2 questions ? Is it adding the data to the ratings ? What is the data type of storyidr ?

Comment: err, so it looks like you mean your rate.php to return the new average?  why aren't you doing that then?

Comment: it is adding the value to the SQL table, yes. the data is two things. 1.A # representing the rating (1-5). 2.The id# of the item being rated, I'm labeling 'product id' in the above code. I just cant figure out how to display the new value from SQL.

Comment: Hi ysth, yes that's what i'm having problems with. Lost on how to do it.

Comment: Anhik, storyid is a integer.it is the same as 'productid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSON format to send back the result using **json_encode**

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[productID]','$_POST[value]',now())");

if(!$result)
{
      $arr = array ('status'=>'fail');
      echo json_encode($arr);
}
else
{
        $arr = array ('status'=>'success');
        echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

In the success callback you can have the status using object.status (data.status in your case)